# MPAndroidChart - How to draw bar at bottom of line chart

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I want to draw stock's history price chart with volume, similar to this:

[image]

With [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart), I managed to get this result using `CombinedChart`:

[image]

Here's my code snippet:

```
CombinedChart mChart = (CombinedChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);

final ArrayList<BarEntry> barList = new ArrayList<>();
final ArrayList<Entry> lineList = new ArrayList<>();

// add Bar & Line data entries
.....

// bar depends on LEFT y-axis
BarDataSet barSet = new BarDataSet(barList, "");
barSet.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
BarData barData = new BarData(barSet);

// line depends on RIGHT y-axis
LineDataSet lineSet = new LineDataSet(lineList, "");
lineSet.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT);
LineData lineData = new LineData(lineSet);

// set data to chart
....

float barYMax = barData.getYMax();
float lineYMin = lineData.getYMin();

// to make bar appears at bottom
YAxis leftAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
leftAxis.setAxisMaximum(barYMax * 10);

// to make line appears at top
YAxis rightAxis = mChart.getAxisRight();
rightAxis.setAxisMinimum(lineYMin * 0.5f);
```

In order to make `"Line Chart" appears above "Bar Chart"`:

1. Bar chart depends on Left y-axis. To make bar appears at bottom, I make it's scale larger, with `leftAxis.setAxisMaximum(barYMax * 10)`.
2. Line chart depends on Right y-axis. To shift line up, I do `rightAxis.setAxisMinimum(lineYMin * 0.5f)`.

I wonder is there a better recommended way to achieve this effect?

With my solution, line chart may still overlap with bar partially. Ideally I wish to achieve `no overlapping` at all, with `line appears completely on top of bar`.